# Merging events from one selector to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if it's possible to store the events from a jQuery selector and apply it to another selector?

Something similar to $('selector').clone(true) but actually clones the events only and not the element.

```
$('.class1').on('click.click1', function(e) {
alert('click 1')
});

$('.class2').on('click.click2', function(e) {
    alert('click 2')
});

// pseudo
$('.class2') cloneEvents from $('.class1');
```

Comment: Do you mean like using functions?

Comment: I think he wants to clone the events from one element to another, correct? As in check what events are being listen for in element1 and duplicate them to element2?

Comment: Not even to element but a particular selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick and dirty jQuery plugin for this purpose**

This reads the event handlers bound to `$source` via jQuery using the internal method `_data`, iterates over them and binds them to `$target`. Derived from this [snippet](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=64750).

```
;(function($, doc, win) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.cloneEventsFrom = function($source) {
        var $this = $(this),
        source = $source.get(0);

        $.each($._data(source, 'events'), function() {
            $.each(this, function() {
               $this.bind(this.type, this.handler);
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery, document, window);
```

**Usage** Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/4Jv37/1/

```
var $target = $('.target'),
    $source = $('.source')

$target.cloneEventsFrom($source);
```